# Loop does not print out correct output

Tags: python

```
x = int(input('Enter x: '))
y = int(input('Enter y: '))

product = 0
## 50 in border
border = str('-------------------------------------------------------')
print(border)
print('%15s' % 'x', '%15s' % 'y', '%23s' % 'product')
print(border)

if y < x:
    temp = x
    x = y
    y = temp
xTwo = x
yTwo = y

productTwo = x*y

while not x <= 0:

    if x % 2 == 0:
        x = x / 2
        y = y*2

    else: 
        x = x - 1
        product = product + y

    print('%15d' % x, '%15d' % y, '%23d' % int(product))

else:
    print(border)
    print(xTwo, '*', yTwo, '=', productTwo)
```

**Below is what it produces. In the loop I want the first number line to read ' 12 14 0 ' but i am not sure where I need to place the print line for that to happen or if i can change the loop slightly to produce that result ****

```
Enter x: 12
Enter y: 14
-------------------------------------------------------
          x               y                 product
-------------------------------------------------------
          6              28                     168
          3              56                     168
          2              56                     224
          1             112                     224
          0             112                     336
-------------------------------------------------------
12 * 14 = 168
```

Comment: try putting the print line right after the loop starts: `while not x <= 0:
    print('%15d' % x, '%15d' % y, '%23d' % int(product))`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the location of the print statement. You need to place it on the first line of the while loop. If you do not do this then the x%2=0 condition becomes true and x value is changed.

```
x = int(input('Enter x: '))
y = int(input('Enter y: '))

product = 0
## 50 in border
border = str('-------------------------------------------------------')
print(border)
print('%15s' % 'x', '%15s' % 'y', '%23s' % 'product')
print(border)

if y < x:
    temp = x
    x = y
    y = temp
xTwo = x
yTwo = y

productTwo = x*y

while not x <= 0:
    print('%15d' % x, '%15d' % y, '%23d' % int(product))

    if x % 2 == 0:
        x = x / 2
        y = y*2

    else: 
        x = x - 1
        product = product + y


else:
    print(border)
    print(xTwo, '*', yTwo, '=', productTwo)
```